# Send select2 value from dropdown to flask

Tags: ajax, flask, select, jquery-select2

I have a dropdown select2 field with 3 different values. But how can i send the selected value from the dropdown to a variable in my flask program? Here´s my following code and what i tried so far

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                //var hugo=document.getElementById("fmea").value;
                $(document).on('submit','#form',function(e)
                               {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'/index',
                    data:{
                      event:$("#event").val(),
                      context:$("#context").val(),
                      //'fmea[]':$("#fmea.select2").val() 
                      //fmea:$('.test').select2(content[0]) 
                      fmea:JSON.stringify(fmea)
                    },
                    //traditional:true,
                    success:function()
                    {
           
                      draw();
                    }
                  })
                });
            </script>
```

*select2*

```
<script>
                var content = [
                    {id: 0, text: "Event1"},
                    {id: 1, text: "Event2 "},
                    {id: 2, text: "Event4"},
                ];
            
            
                $(".test").select2({
                     data:content,
                     // minimumInputLength: 2,
                     width: '35%',
                     multiple:true,
                     placeholder:"Enter another event",
                     // templateResult:formatState
            
                });
```

and the html code

```
<form method="post" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <input type="text" name="event" id="event" class="btn" placeholder="Event" >
                                    <input type="text" name="context" id="context" class="btn" placeholder="Context" >
                                    <input type ="text" name="fmea" id="fmea" class="btn test" placeholder="Select another Event">
                                    <br>
                                    <br>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="hide()" >Show Graph</button>                                    
</form>
```

and python

```
fmea=request.form.get("fmea")
```

I´m getting the first two input values easily, but the fmea tag returns None. If you could give me a hint how to get the selected value, I´d appreciate it very much.

***Edit***
Via a db connection, i´m getting data which i store in a python list. This list i want to pass to select2 so the user can select the value.

***app.py***

```
@application.route("/autocomplete",methods=["POST","GET"])
def autocomplete():
    #getting topic names
    q1="MATCH (n:Topic) RETURN n"
    nodes=neo4j_session.run(q1)
    node_result = nodes.data()
    node_raw=list() 
    for d in node_result:
        for key in d:
            node_raw.append(d[key])
    nodes=list()
    for i in node_raw: 
        nodes.append(i['Name'])

    
    return jsonify(nodes)

@application.route('/index', methods=["POST","GET"])
def index():
    
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        df=pd.DataFrame()
        topic=request.form.getlist("topic")
        topic=''.join(str(x) for x in topic)
        print(topic)
        query=get_final_query(topic) 
        results=neo4j_session.run(query).data()
        df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(results)
        #df=df.drop_duplicates()
        df=df.reset_index(drop=True)
        
               
        return render_template("dashboard.html",query=query,tables=[df.to_html(classes="table table-striped table-hover table-sm",header=True)])
    return render_template("dash.html")
```

select2 right now

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript">
          (function(contentUri, dataUri) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $('select[name="topic"]').select2({
                  ajax: {
                      url: "/index",
                      dataType: 'json' 
                  }, 
                  width: '35%',
                  multiple: true,
                  placeholder: 'Enter another event'
              });
  
              $('form[name="myform"]').bind(function(evt) {
                  //evt.preventDefault();
                  $.ajax({
                      method: 'POST',
                      url: dataUri,
                      data: $(this).serialize()
                  }).done(function(data) {
                      $('output[name="result"]').html(data.selected.join(','));
                  })
              });
            });
          })({{ url_for('.autocomplete') | tojson }});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example below shows you how to submit a form with a select box like yours to the server using AJAX.

As soon as a submit event is fired, the entire form is formatted accordingly via the [`serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function and then sent.
Since you have chosen a variant of the selection field in which several options can be selected, the `ImmutableMultiDict` provided by the `request.form` object contains a list of tuples. In this case you can use `request.form.getlist(...)` to query the values contained using the name of the selection box, as you already know from other input fields. The return value corresponds to a list with the selected values. These are automatically converted by specifying the type parameter.

###### Flask (app.py)

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask import (
    render_template, 
    request, 
    jsonify
)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/data', methods=['POST'])
def data():
    events = request.form.getlist('events', type=int)
    return jsonify(selected=events)
```

###### HTML (templates/index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Select2 Example</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="my-form" method="post">
      <select name="events"></select>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <output name="result"></output>

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function(uri) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
          const content = [
            {id: 0, text: 'Event 1'},
            {id: 1, text: 'Event 2'},
            {id: 2, text: 'Event 3'},
          ];
          $('select[name="events"]').select2({
            data: content,
            width: '35%',
            multiple: true,
            placeholder: 'Enter another event'
          });

          $('form[name="my-form"]').submit(function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
              method: 'POST',
              url: uri,
              data: $(this).serialize()
            }).done(function(data) {
              $('output[name="result"]').html(data.selected.join(','));
            })
          });
        });
      })({{ url_for('.data') | tojson }});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

If you want to pass the selectbox entries through from python, you can pass them to the template. Within your JavaScript code you then use the jinja filter `tojson` to convert the list into a JavaScript array.

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask import (
    render_template, 
    request, 
    jsonify
)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    items = [
        { 'id': 0, 'text': 'Event 1' },
        { 'id': 1, 'text': 'Event 2' },
        { 'id': 2, 'text': 'Event 3' },
    ]
    return render_template('index.html', **locals())

@app.route('/data', methods=['POST'])
def data():
    events = request.form.getlist('events', type=int)
    return jsonify(selected=events)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Select2 Example</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

   <form name="my-form" method="post">
      <select name="events"></select>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <output name="result"></output>

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function(uri, content) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('select[name="events"]').select2({
            data: content,
            width: '35%',
            multiple: true,
            placeholder: 'Enter another event'
          });

          $('form[name="my-form"]').submit(function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
              method: 'POST',
              url: uri,
              data: $(this).serialize()
            }).done(function(data) {
              $('output[name="result"]').html(data.selected.join(','));
            })
          });
        });
      })({{ url_for('.data') | tojson }}, {{ items | tojson }});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As an alternative, you can also get the list via AJAX.

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask import (
    render_template, 
    request, 
    jsonify
)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/content')
def content():
    q = request.args.get('q', '')

    items = [
        { 'id': 0, 'text': 'Event 1'},
        { 'id': 1, 'text': 'Event 2'},
        { 'id': 2, 'text': 'Event 3'},
    ]

    results = [item for item in items if q in item['text']]

    return jsonify(results=results)

@app.route('/data', methods=['POST'])
def data():
    events = request.form.getlist('events', type=int)
    return jsonify(selected=events)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Select2 Example</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

   <form name="my-form" method="post">
      <select name="events"></select>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <output name="result"></output>

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function(contentUri, dataUri) {
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $('select[name="events"]').select2({
                ajax: {
                    url: contentUri,
                    dataType: 'json' 
                }, 
                width: '35%',
                multiple: true,
                placeholder: 'Enter another event'
            });

            $('form[name="my-form"]').submit(function(evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: dataUri,
                    data: $(this).serialize()
                }).done(function(data) {
                    $('output[name="result"]').html(data.selected.join(','));
                })
            });
          });
        })({{ url_for('.content') | tojson }}, {{ url_for('.data') | tojson }});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

###### Update

I have to admit that I haven't worked with neo4j yet. Nevertheless, I tried to work out a solution, which I can't test at the moment.
The idea is that you are asking for an entry's id and name, giving the id the alias id and renaming the name property to text.
For filtering to work, you should search for the name that matches the query parameter.
It is sorted according to the name property.
Then iterates over all results and each entry is turned into a dict. The resulting list is returned as a nested property for results in JSON format.

```py
def autocomplete():
    q = request.args.get('q', '')
    query = "MATCH (n:Topic) "\
        "WHERE toLower(n.name) CONTAINS toLower($qs) "\
        "RETURN id(n) AS id, n.name AS text "\
        "ORDER BY n.name"
    nodes = neo4j_session.run(query, qs=q)
    items = [{k:v for k,v in node.items()} for node in nodes]
    return jsonify(results=items)
```

Comment: thanks, that´s what i was looking for :)

Comment: what would be needed if i don´t want to get the id of the selected value, but the text of the it and store it in the python variable?

Comment: A select box consists of a select element and several option elements. These each have a value attribute. The content of this value attribute is set by the parameter `id` of the respective entry. This can be chosen freely. So you don't necessarily have to use a number as `id`, but you can also use the text that is also in the `text` parameter.

Comment: Hi @Detlef, may i ask how you can fill the content array by passing a python list?

Comment: @fipse I added two possibilities to my answer and I hope I was able to help you with your problem. If you don't understand something or I didn't answer your question sufficiently, leave me a comment.

Comment: hi @detlfef, i updated my question so maybe it´s clearer now. Thanks for your support, very appreciated!

Comment: @fipse I have already read your last question. Problem is, I haven't used neo4j yet, so I've avoided replying to it. Nevertheless, I tried to work out a solution, but I'm absolutely not sure if it works. Please give me a feedback if you get it to work.